# Linux shell script Date arithmetic

Tags: linux, shell, date

I have a shell script

```
 #!/bin/bash
START=$(date +%s)
echo "  Start| $START "
# do something
# start your script work here
#  
# your logic ends here
END=$(date +%s)
echo "  End|  $END "
DIFF=$(( $END-$START ))
echo "  Diff in seconds|"  $DIFF
```

Still getting this error
  Start| 1349769151
  End|  1349769151
 ")49769151rror: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

I know it is basic, so I have been searched and debug for two days already.
But still gets nothing works on this.
Plz help!

Answer (score 3):

The START and END are not in date format which can't be subtracted. If you just want to measure the execution time then use only %s which will give you difference in seconds.

```
START=$(date +%s)
echo "  Start| $START "
# do something
# start your script work here
#  
# your logic ends here
END=$(date +%s)
echo "  End|  $END "
DIFF=$(( $END-$START ))
echo "Diff in seconds:" $DIFF
```

Comment: hi, KingsIndian, I changed my code like you show. But still getting some error. Help!

Comment: What error you get? It works ok for me. Can you check if you have the same code?

Comment: Still getting this error Start| 1349769151 End| 1349769151 ")49769151rror: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Comment: There's no error in this part, you have some error where you have `do something`. Check the code you have in between calculating the time.

Comment: if you don't have any other code then it should work without error. To see some difference use `sleep 5`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to perform arithmetic operations with strings: it will not work.

I suggest you to print the date as a timestamp with `date "+%s"` and use those numbers for your math.